# Elasticsearch: how to return all facet values in an aggregation

Tags: elasticsearch

I am learning Elasticsearch by reading the book called Elasticsearch Cookbook (2ed). It has the following sample query:

```
{
    "query": {
        "match_all": {}
    },
    "aggs": {
        "tag": {
            "terms": {
                "field": "tag",
                "size": 10
            }
        }
    }
}
```

According to the book,

```
size (by default 10): This controls the number of facets value that is to be returned.
```

I am curious about this: how to return all facet values if I don't know the total number of facet values in advance?

Sorry if my question is so obvious.

Thanks and regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set size to 0 (which is the same as setting it to Integer.MAX_VALUE)

Be careful though, as this will perform horribly if you have a lot of facet values.

See http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html

Comment: Thanks so much for your help!! I can see a bit inconsistency in ES API. I know that when doing an aggregation search, size=0 on the REST url means returning NO documents, but just buckets. Now for ALL facet values, we use size=0 again here. Your thought?

Comment: I think thats a fair criticism